# How can I run my application in background (VB 2008-10)?

Tags: vb.net, background, icons

Sorry if such a question like this has been posted before. How do I make my VB application run in background so that I can click on the hidden icons in the tray of hidden icons (near the clock and the date) of my Windows 7 PC and re-activate it?

I tried to hide my form to do this, but I did not know how to re-activate its window back. On the `OnClick()` method of my button `cmdRunBG`, I typed:

```
Me.visible = false
```

Well, that thing just hid the form. I want it to *really* run in the background, having an icon in the tray of icons (near the system clock). How do I do that?

If you have any clarifications regarding this, please respond.

Thanks.

Comment: The user can just minimize your application. There's absolutely no need to have an extra button to perform that standard action.

Comment: An icon in the taskbar means that your window is visible and usable, possibly minimized, there is no rare behaviors here.
Or maybe you want to put an icon in the **tray**? (on the right side, besides the clock)

Comment: Yes sir, you said it rightly... That's what I want. I want it put in the tray...(near the clock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is to programmatically minimize your form. Try that:

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to put the application on system tray, a simple way to do it is the following:

1. add a NotifyIcon control to your application and set its properties
2. add the following code in the `Resize` event of your form:

   ```
   If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
      Me.Hide()
   End If
   ```
3. add the following code in the `MouseClick` event of your NotifyIcon:

   ```
   If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
       Me.Show()
       Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
   End If
   ```

Comment: As Alejandro said, I'd like it put in the tray near the clock. Not just minimize it...

Comment: @SandyMan: I see, in that case things are more complicated. You might find [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176085) helpful.

Comment: @SandyMan: I have extended my answer with a simple example of how you can do this.